# How to kill a continuous process started from rc.local?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (Debian-based) OS. For testing I added such a command in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
python /home/pi/test.py
```

It works fine starting this script. But the problem is that I forgot that there is an infinite loop in the script, something like:

```
while True:
    print 'Hello"
    time.sleep(5)
```

This loop blocks the system to boot, so I can't enter the system to edit the script. Ctrl+C doesn't work to kill it. So I wonder how to kill a continuous process started from `rc.local`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot kill the process interactively from the console but you have multiple options how to avoid running of it during boot.

### a) Boot in a single user mode

Append `s` separated by space to the line in `cmdline.txt` in the boot partition (FAT). After booting you can either rename `/etc/rc.local`, make it non-executable (`chmod a-x /etc/rc.local`) or edit it.

### b) Boot with a shell instead of `init`

Append `init=/bin/sh` separated by space to the line in `cmdline.txt`. This will bypass starting of any boot scripts. Then you can make the same measures against `/etc/rc.local` as above.

### c) Mount the Linux partition in a different system

Put the SD card to a different system and mount the partition with `/etc/rc.local` there. Then you can make the same measures against `/etc/rc.local` as above.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same kind of application which play infinitely after reboot. For any changes, I mount that to another system and do the changes and put it back to my board. Its the easiest way to do so.